# 'You must prompt for the data '-says in python coding problem, but I don't know what's wrong with my code?

Tags: python-3.x

Write a program to prompt the user for hours and rate per hour using input to compute gross pay.
 Pay should be the normal rate for hours up to 40 and time-and-a-half for the hourly rate for all hours worked above 40 hours.
 Put the logic to do the computation of pay in a function called computepay() and use the function to do the computation. The function should return a value.
 Use **45 hours** and a rate of **10.50 per hour** to test the program (the pay should be **498.75**). You should use input to read a string and float() to convert the string to a number. 
Do not worry about error checking the user input unless you want to - you can assume the user types numbers properly. Do not name your variable sum or use the sum() function.

I tried this using my pc IDE and got similar output as required.
 But I got error that:

> You must prompt for the data.

What's the problem? I mean,when do we get such errors?

```
prompt1 = "Enter Hours:"
prompt2 = "Enter Rate:"
def computepay(h,r):
    if h > 40:
        pay = ((h -40)*.5 + h)*10.50
    else:
        pay = h*10.50
    return pay

hrs = int(input(prompt1))
rate = float(input(prompt2))
ans = computepay(hrs,rate)
print("Pay",ans)`
```

Comment: You gave us your assignment, and your code, but did not explain the problem you're having with that code. Please [edit] your post to include a clear problem description; *I don't know what's wrong* isn't a question, and you've not explained what issue you're having.

Comment: I think this problem is from python for every body by dr. Chuck. I will give you scenario what exactly it is expecting: if user gives proper input for hours and rate that's fine otherwise you need to calculate automatically for 45 hrs for the rate of 10.50 per hour.

Comment: Please clear it, if you are sure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
hrs = input("Enter Hours : ")
rate = input("Enter rate : ")

Fhours =  float(hrs)
Frate = float(rate)

def computepay(Fhours,Frate):
    if Fhours <= 40 :
        p=Fhours*Frate
    else:
        p=((40 * Frate) + ((Fhours - 40) * (Frate * 1.5)))
    return p

p = computepay(Fhours,Frate)
print("Pay",p)
```

By the way it's an assignment from cousera **"python for everybody"** :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did for your problem. Hope this helps.

```
#Beaufuh
#Follow me on Twitter @Beaufuhh

#Try getting the user's input as a number
try:
    hours = float(input('Enter hours: '))
    rate = float(input('Enter hourly rate: '))
#if user's input is not a number return Entry error.
except ValueError:
    print('Entry error. ')
#if the user's input is more than 40, calculate overtime.
if hours > 40: 
    overtime = float(hours - 40) 
#Tell the user how many hours they worekd and what they earned for the week, with overtime considered.'''
    print(f'You worked {hours} hours this week and earned ${(hours*rate) + (overtime*(rate*1.5))} dollars.')
#Tell the user how many hours they worked and what they earend for the week.
else:
    print(f'You worked {hours} hours this week and earned ${(hours*rate)} dollars.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the code given below. It will work.

```
Hrs = input("Enter Hours:")
Pay = input("Enter Pay: ")

hrs = float(Hrs)
pay = float(Pay)

def computepay(hrs,pay):
       if hrs <= 40 :
           p=hrs*pay
       else:
           p=((40 * pay) + ((hrs - 40) * (pay * 1.5)))
       return p

d = computepay(hrs,pay)
print("Pay",d)
```

Comment: I wanted to fix my problem, not solution ever bro!

Answer (score 0):

The system of `py4e` require you to get the rate from user. I see you use `"10.5"` instead of `"r"` for python to compute, just change the function like this:

```
if h>=40:
    pay = ((h -40)*.5 + h)****r***   (10.5 - r)
return ans
```

Answer (score 0):

The question requires input from the prompt
But in the existing code a parameterized function is used so we need to change that code to a simple function.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by providing some sample code?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, the problem was - I was not passing 2 arguments to the function, once that was fixed it worked well. Below is the code.

```
def computepay(hours,rate_per_hr):
    if hours:
        grosspay = hours * rate_per_hr
        if hours > 40:
            grosspay += (hours-40)* rate_per_hr * 0.5      
    return grosspay    

hours = float(input("Enter the hours: "))
rate_per_hr = float(input("Enter the rate: "))

print('Pay',computepay(hours,rate_per_hr))
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occurred because you have used a given value for the rate which is supposed to be prompted. Try removing the value of 10.50 in your program and replace it with a given variable in your case (r). This has to be prompted by the user, remember that. See this,

```
 p = 40*r +(h-40)*1.5*r
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put hrs and rate inside the function

I did it like this and it worked:

```
def computepay(h, r):
    h = int(hrs)
    r = float(rate)
    if h <= 40:
        totalpay = h * r
    else:
        totalpay = (((h-40) * (r* 1.5)) + (40 * r))
    return totalpay


hrs = input("Enter Hours:")
rate = input("Enter Rate:")
p = computepay(hrs, rate)
print("Pay", p)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must prompt for the data: What this does mean is the variable (r or rate) you have defined that should have taken the value as input from the user. You defined the function to take the value from the user. But later on you rather than using the input value of rate, you used a constant (equal to 10.5) in your code.

```
def computepay(h,r):
    if h > 40:
        pay = ((h -40) * 10.5 * 1.5) + (40 * 10.5)
    else:
        pay = h * 10.50
    return pay
```

So you should have prompted the data from input to your formula as follows:

```
def computepay(h,r):
    if h > 40:
        pay = ((h - 40) * r * 1.5) + (40 * r)
    else:
        pay = h * r
    return pay
```

Rest of the code remains the same.

Answer (score -1):

I've got the same "error" message. So I guess he problem is you count with the fix value for the rate (10.50). Try to use your rate variable instead of the fix10.50 value

Answer (score -2):

you may write the exact amounts in the arguments. Try to write variable names.
Try This:

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/606Fg.jpg)

You will get the desired result!

Comment: [Please don't upload images of code when answering a question](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Instead, please [edit] your answer to include your code as [formatted text](/editing-help#code).